# Installation of Memcache and Memcached

Tags: php, laravel

There are a lot of tutorials about how to install memcache(d). I managed to do it.
Used this to create an object, everything is working fine

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

But when I try with "new Memcached"

```
$memcache = new Memcached;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

There is an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found
```

I have php_memcache.dll in php directory and configuration goes:

```
extension=php_memcache.dll
[Memcache]
memcache.allow_failover = 1
memcache.max_failover_attempts=20
memcache.chunk_size =8192
memcache.default_port = 11211
```

But what about **memcached**. Laravel is using it and I cannot cache anything using memcache because of that error.

Comment: If you run `phpinfo()` do you see any info about Memcache?

Comment: Here https://i.imgsafe.org/919d4bc.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install memcached library, "Memcache"  and "Memcached" are 2 separate libraries, you have to install them from pecl https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached
https://pecl.php.net/package/memcache

when you have both their libraries, the y will be available for you to use.

Comment: Thank you, I need to compile those libraries to get dll right?

Comment: of course, as stated on php documentation page http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php